# ConcurrentModification Exception with Map and Hashtable

Tags: java, exception, collections

In my application I have used a Map to store POJO objects. As per the requirement I need to iterate over the keySet of the Map and remove objects which dont need any modification.

Conside the code below:

```
 public void remove(Map<String,User> removeUser){
  Set<String> keySet = removeUser.keySey();
  User user = null;

  for(String key : keySet){
      user = (user) removeUser.get(key);

       if(!user.isActive()){
                removeUser.remove(key);
       }
  }

 }
```

Here in above code, I am getting ConcurrentModificationException when I try to fetch User object after Object removal.

Can anyone tell me why it's happening?

I have not used multi threading.So not able to understand, from where it generated ConCurrentModification Exception.

Even I tried with HashMap and Hashtable, but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> from where it generated ConCurrentModification Exception.

It came from the line where you are trying to remove the element from your `Map` while iterating over its `KeySet`.

```
if(!user.isActive()){
     removeUser.remove(key);  // This is the problem
}
```

You should not do that. If you want to modify your `Collection` or `Map`, use an `iterator`.

---

See this very nice post - [efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection) explaining the problems that can come while modifying the collection you iterate upon.

---

Here's a simple code explaining how you can use it here: -

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
        {
            put("a", 1);
            put("b", 2);
            put("c", 3);
        }
    };

    Iterator<String> iterate = map.keySet().iterator();

    while  (iterate.hasNext()) {
        int i = map.get(iterate.next());

        if(i > 1) {
            iterate.remove();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(map);
```

**OUTPUT: -**

```
{a=1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Good Explanation.  I referred this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html. Here they have given good explanation about ConcurrentModificationException  on Structure change of a map.

Comment: @GunjanShah.. Yeah of course that's the documentation link. And has a good and concise explanation on this stuff. Please keep on referring documentation to learn about the various methods in Java. :)

Comment: Ahhh! I entered that on my iphone from memory. I was sure entry had remove()! crap

Comment: @Bohemian.. haha :) No problem.. It happens sometimes. Its difficult to remember every method of every class though. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

If you use ConcurrentHashMap it won't produce a ConcurrentModificationException.

The more general solution is to use the Iterator to do the remove().

```
public void removeInactiveUsers(Map<String, User> map) {
    for (Iterator<User> iter = map.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) 
        if (!user.isActive())
            iter.remove();
}
```

Note: you don't need the `keySet()` as you are only interested in the `values()`

Comment: Yeah that is also valid point. Just using `values` is enough. +1 for that.

Comment: @Bohemian I would argue getting the `entrySet()` and having to call `getValue()` is also more than you need. `Map.Entry.remove()` doesn't exist, so that's cheating a little ;)

Comment: Ahhh! I entered that on my iphone from memory. I was sure entry had remove()! crap.

Comment: @Bohemian My in memory IDE is buggy too. ;)

Answer (score 2):

use an iterator to iterate over your **Set** and use `iterator.remove()`, you cant **remove** elements from your **collection** while iterating over it.you'd get a **ConcurrentModification Exception**

**root cause** of your Exception is here:

```
        removeUser.remove(key);
```

iterate over your set like this, using an iterator.

```
Iterator<String> itr = keySet .iterator();
while(itr.hasNext){
   String s = itr.next();
   itr.remove(); // to remove the current element.
 }
```